# What are the relationships between Kubernetes services and clusters and Google Compute Engine objects?

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am setting a couple of services running on Google Container Engine, with traffic coming in through a Google HTTP Load Balancer, using path mapping.

There is a good Google tutorial on setting up content-based load-balancing [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/content-based-example), but it is all in terms of plain Google Compute objects like instance groups and backend services. I, however, have Kubernetes services, pods and clusters.

What is the relationship between the Kubernetes objects and the Google Compute resources? How do I map between the two programmatically?

(I am aware that I could be using a Kubernetes web ingress object to do the balancing, as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#step_3_create_an_ingress_object), but it looks like Kubernetes Ingress does not yet support HTTPS, which need.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the relationship between the Kubernetes objects and the Google Compute resources? How do I map between the two programmatically?

https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/Ingress/controllers/gce#overview

> (I am aware that I could be using a Kubernetes web ingress object to do the balancing, as explained here, but it looks like Kubernetes Ingress does not yet support HTTPS, which need.)

Ingress will support HTTPS in 1.2. This is what the resource will look like: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/19497#issuecomment-174112834. In the meanwhile you can setup HTTP loadbalancing with the Ingress and hand modify it to support https. Apologies beforehand that this is convoluted, it will get better soon.

First create an HTTP Ingress:

1. Create Services of [Type=NodePort](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/user-guide/services.md#type-nodeport)
2. Make sure you have [BackendService quota](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/cluster-loadbalancing/glbc#prerequisites)
3. Create a [HTTP Ingress](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer)
4. Expose the node port (s) of the service in the Firewall (also as mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer)
5. Wait till kubect describe ing shows [HEALTHY for you backends](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/cluster-loadbalancing/glbc#latency).

At this point you should be able to curl your Ingress loadbalancer IP and hit the nginx service (or whatever service you created in step 1).

Then do the following, manually through the [GCE console](https://console.developers.google.com):

1. Change the IP of the Ingress resource from "Ephmermal" to "Static" (look for the IP in `kubectl get ing` in the "External IP addresses" tab)
2. Create your ssl cert. If you just want a self signed cert you can do:

> openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /tmp/nginx.key -out /tmp/nginx.crt -subj "/CN=nginxsvc/O=nginxsvc"

3. Create a new target HTTPS proxy and forwarding rule for the HTTPS load balancer and assign it to the same (static) IP of the http load balancer.

At this point you should be able to curl https://loadbalancer-ip -k

Comment: The link to the GLBC doc is very helpful, thank you. However, I still have the question of how to add other GCE concepts to the ingress, or add services from outside that k8s cluster to the ingress. In particular, I have a gcloud compute 'address', which I'd like to use for this ingress; is there a way for me to specify that in the yaml file? If not, is it possible to specify on the command line using gcloud? (I am trying to have a reproducible process here, hence trying to avoid the UI console as much as possible.)

Comment: Hi Ana (it's been a while)! I think your best bet may be to side-step the ingress object all together and just configure your own custom L7 load balancing config. Then you can use all of the advanced features in the balancer configuration that aren't exposed through the ingress abstraction.

Comment: You will have to import that service into Kubernetes first, as a NodePort service, and point the Ingress to that NodePort Service. You can import it by creating a service without selectors:https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/user-guide/services.md#services-without-selectors (make sure the Type of the Service is NodePort, and the Endpoint you create has the IP of your external service). At this point it is just like any other NodePort service. Note that you're bouncing L7 -> k8s Node -> your external service, so this is obviously sub-optimal in terms of performance.

Comment: Thanks Robert and Prashant. I followed Robert's suggestion (with more details in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446512/is-it-possible-to-use-1-kubernetes-ingress-object-to-route-traffic-to-k8s-servic), and it worked quite nicely. The key insight that I was missing was realizing that a k8s cluster is equivalent to a compute instance group, and I can just set my NodePort as a named port on the group and then treat it all as a regular compute service for configuring behind a balancer.